# I want to automatically add all new leads or contacts to a general introduction campaign

Tags: leads, contact, campaign

I know how to import lists of leads or contacts in to a campaign.

However I want figure out how to set it up so that if a new lead or contact is created in salesforce - either by import or individuals making new ones - they will automatically be added to the general introduction campaign without any other criteria/filters needed.

I am new to all of this so try to keep it simple. :-)